# Como mudo a cor do switch do bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="teste">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="teste">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O switch do bootstrap é feito criando dois elemento dentro da `label` com a classe "custom-control-label", você pode criar algumas regras de CSS para se aplicar a eles, como por exemplo:

```css
.custom-switch .custom-control-label::after{
    background-color: red;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-label::before {
    border-color: red;
}
```

[image: Print de um "switch" com a cor vermelha, resultado do código acima]

Comment: Perfeito Sergio Carvalho, muito obrigado, me salvou!

Comment: Só uma dúvida, ele ativo como mudo a cor?

Comment: Ao ser ativo o input recebe uma propriedade "checked". Você pode criar a seguinte regra CSS para aplicar quando ele estiver ativo:

.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    color: #fff;
    border-color:  red;
    background-color :red;
}

.custom-switch .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
    background-color: #c55d5d;
}`

Aqui o CSS já não é tão básico, mas é o gerado pelo próprio bootstrap, um ótimo material de estudo

Comment: Adicionei a propriedade, mas infelimente continuou padrão, teria uma outra solução amigo?

Comment: Pronto não, recomendo você utilizar a função de inspecionar elemento e ver como o css do bootstrap é aplicado, e ir mudando até encontrar o resultado diário. Assim você saberá quais classe mudar

Comment: Até fiz dessa forma, mas nada está dando certo, mas sua ajuda já foi um pontapé inicial amigo vlw